# Setting up an IRC server

Tags: windows, irc

I am currently trying to set up an IRC server in windows. I just finished my config file which just changes a couple of things and lets you connect to the server, but every time I start UnrealIRCd it does not succesfully start. Instead it logs the following error: `Error binding stream socket to IP {my ip address} port 6667`

I have the config file written out correctly and very simply, just changing the keys, IP addresses and ports.

My only problem is when I open unrealircd to start running the server it never runs it, does anyone know whats wrong or how to fix this?

Comment: Please [edit] and provide more detail.

Comment: You might also want to have a look at log files produced by the application. Those often give you a clue about what is going wrong. If it doesn't start at all, it is likely an error in your config file.

Comment: ok, after checking the log im getting this error "Error binding stream socket to IP {my ip address} port 6667, ive tried multiple ports too, any ideas?, could it be a router issue

Comment: @Shantanu Is the address of the PC you are running the server same as the IP address in the configuration, or are you using a public address in the config and your server has a private address?

Comment: im using the same public server for both